# jQuery.noConflict() causing error in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code for this plugin http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/

```
// <![CDATA[
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.defaultval').defaultValue();
    }); 
// ]]>
```

the `$.noConflict();` is giving me `$ is not a function` in another script in this line

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
```

"autocomplete" is for the jquery UI autocomplete plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

How can I fix this issue? Removing `$.noConflict();` seems to solve it but I want to leave because I think it was put for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `noConflict` function removes jQuery's `$` alias, to allow other libraries to use `$` instead.

You cannot use `noConflict` with code that uses `$`, unless you wrap that code in a function with its own `$` alias by writing `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: Hmm I see.. but what other libraries would use it? HTML 5 perhaps? The plugin is a fallback for the placeholder supported in HTML 5.

Comment: HTML5 is a set of loosely related browser standards, not a library.  `$` is used by libraries like Prototype.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might remove noConflict completely since I'm not using any other scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the autocomplete in it's own private closure:

```
var jQueryVariableForMyUseOnly = jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){

    $(...).autocomplete(...);

})(jQueryVariableForMyUseOnly);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `})(jQuery)`?  noConflict only removes the $ alias, not jquery itself.

Comment: Yes you can, I just find this cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

just change this:

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
```

to this:

```
jQuery( "#city" ).autocomplete({
```

noConflict removes the alias on $ but jQuery still exists.

EDIT: alternatively, you can assign the alias to something else, for instance:

```
$j = $.noConflict();
$j("#city").autocomplete({
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

edit: upon re-reading your question. this won't solve anything.  nothing to see here.